# Acumatica Formula Unsupported

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I am building a GI in Acumatica. I a have it all completed, but I am getting the error: (Unsupported formula operator 'IIf.')

I used some extensive relationships to try and get the result I want and need.

These are the tables and relationships used:

[image: Tables]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

These snippets were took from and GI created by Tim Rodman on a report perpared by: Shawn Slavin.

My tables are little different than these tables, but set up with the same format. Is there any way anyone can point out why I would be getting this error?

Comment: The error message is about 'IF' and the formula in the screenshots show 'IIF'. In the whole GI are you sure there isn't one formula with 'IF' instead of 'IIF'?

Comment: I am sorry I typed the error in wrong it is actually 'IIF' and I checked all the if statements in the GI and They are all 'IIF'.

Comment: Try to see in the traces if you have more details to identify the faulty formula. Otherwise working by elimination should be possible, formulas can be removed until the error disappear.

Comment: I will give it a shot. Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: I still keep getting the error.